# Different Styles Within Vector Layer

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, vector, style

Is there any way to configure OpenLayers styling method? I have a vector layer and I would like to style the features depending on a value of a flag variables, so I can't use rules. Lets say I have two types of features: houses and restaurants. houses flag is "H" and restaurants flag is "R". How can I give them a different style within a vector layer?

**EDIT**

```
function search(term)
{
var flag;
      if (regex_3.test(term))   //term is 3 letters
         {
     flag = "H";
..
..
..
    }

    else  if (regex_more.test(term))    
            {
     flag = "R";
..
..
    }
}
```

and when I find the feature, I add it to a vector layer.but the thing is I can't find a way to make  two styles depending on the flag value.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think, you can't style a layer based on attributes? It is very much possible.
There are several ways including:

- You can use uniqueValueRules, like shown in this sample: [Unique Value Styles Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/styles-unique.html)
- You could use Context of a style, like given in this sample: [Feature Styles Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/styles-context.html)
- You could create a SLD and apply it to your layer, like given in this sample: [Styled Layer Descriptor (SLD) Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/sld.html)

**Update**
Since you have explained how you are saving the flag, let me explain how you can save that as an attribute of the feature.

I am assuming that you set he flag first (using the `search` function) and then creating the Vector feature.
The constructor for the [Feature Vector](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Feature/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.OpenLayers.Feature.Vector) takes in three parameters:

> geometry  {OpenLayers.Geometry} The geometry that this feature represents.
>
> attributes    {Object} An optional object that will be mapped to the attributes property.
>
> style {Object} An optional style object.

So when you create the feature, you can pass in the flag like this:

```
var feature=new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector( pt, //where pt is your point
             {type:flag}) ; //no style
```

Your styles could be set up using the following lookup object

```
    var lookup = {
        "H": {externalGraphic: "../img/marker-blue.png"},
        "R": {externalGraphic: "../img/marker-green.png"}
    };
```

Another option could be to define two styles, and then after  creating the vector feature, passing the appropriate style, like this:

```
//you have set the flag

//now creating the vector feature
 var feature=new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector( pt); //where pt is your point
if (flag==='H'){
   feature.style=style1;
}else{
   feature.style=style2;
}
```

Comment: you can read more about styling here: http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html

Comment: Thanks. but in the first example, styling depends on "type" property of the features. in my case, i don't want it this way. Flag has nothing to do with feature's properties.

Comment: Isn't the 'flag' one of the attributes of the feature? if not, can you explain how you are storing this 'flag'?

Comment: No. I check the number of type letters. all houses have 3 letters and all restaurants have more that 3 letters, so, when user enter the name of a restaurant in the text field, I check the number of letters, if it's 3 then I store "H" in the flag. and if it's more then I store "R" in the flag.

Comment: and when user click the button, the chosen home/restaurant will have a new style (highlighted). So, I need to know hoe can I assign a new style depending on flag value.

Comment: @Oxi where do you store the flag? is it a Javascript variable? Can you share code of how you are doing it?